# Ask Multiple Save Data Table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to ask, Please help

I tried to create multiple file save data tables

I have a problem when I want to insert multiple fields into one table. all in one table
for the price of all the Data Stored Correctly, but for the type of data stored only the first table, when I enter the 4 tables at once, all the data stored, except for table type he only store the first input, to input data into the same 2,3,4 as the first input

result output like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCiRL.jpg)

sample script that I made like this

```
if($_POST['add']==""){
    foreach ($_POST['price'] as $keyWarna){
        mysql_query("insert into pricedata set id_data='$_POST[id_data]', price='$keyWarna', type='$_POST[type]'");
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yckza.jpg)
For in field type, he only saves Table 1 for the correct data and to field contents do not match the contents of 2,3,4 actually, the first difield input into the table fields 2,3,4

Comment: Your `insert` query is wrong. It should be like this, `mysql_query("insert into pricedata(id_data, price, type) values('{$_POST[id_data]}', '{$keyWarna}', '{$_POST[type]}')");`

Comment: Share yur html also issue in html

Comment: Is input field type also an array?

Comment: the result is the same as mine above,

for the price of all the Data Stored Correctly, but for the type of data stored only the first table, when I enter the 4 tables at once, all the data stored, except for table type he only store the first input, to input data into the same 2,3,4 as the first input

Comment: @url-snort I have share an answer with both example mysql and mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `$_POST['type']` also an array as like `$_POST['price']` than you can use as:

```
foreach ($_POST['price'] as $key => $keyWarna)
{ 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pricedata
(id_data, price, type) VALUES ('$_POST[id_data]', '$keyWarna','$_POST[type][$key]'"); 
}
```

Using $key will help to insert unqiue value.

**Side Note:**  I suggest to use mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_* becuase mysql_* is deprecated and not available in PHP 7

Your code with mysqli_* functions:

```
<?php

// procedural style of mysqli

$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "db";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

if(!$link){
    echo ('unable to connect to database');
}
else {
foreach ($_POST['price'] as $key => $keyWarna)
    { 
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO pricedata
    (id_data, price, type) VALUES ('$_POST[id_data]', '$keyWarna','$_POST[type][$key]'"); 
    }

?>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As you are using price input field

```
<input name='price[]' type='text' />
```

You must need to use type field same as price field like an array for achieving the goal.

```
<input name='type[]' type='text' />
```

**UPDATE 3 (use $i for identification):**

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['price'] as $key => $keyWarna)
{ 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pricedata
(id_data, price, type) VALUES ('$_POST[id_data]', '$keyWarna','$_POST[type][$i]'"); 

$i++;
}
```

Comment: I've tried, data is not can stored
`foreach ($_POST['price'] as $key => $keyWarna)
{ 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pricedata
(id_data, price, type) VALUES ('$_POST[id_data]', '$keyWarna','$_POST[type][$key]'"); 
}`

Comment: @url-snort plz share html as I told

Comment: yes devpro `<table class="table table-bordered no-more-tables" >
       
    <tr>
     <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-cons" id="add" value="add" style="width:100px" /></td>
  
     
    </tr>
 
 </table>`

Comment: @url-snort my friend I am looking for type and price fields

Comment: field type and price, can add tabel auto form, can be inputted own through form input, problems in the process input type, it seems only able to save one input file, 2,3,4 file seems not stored properly, so read the repetition of the first field in the table 2,3,4

Comment: @url-snort yes got yur point I am talking as yur price field is an array . is yur type field is also an array or not just want to see field name

Comment: @url-snort chk compare price field name and type field name both should be an array like price[] and type[]

Comment: how do I solve the problem, in order to process input type can be stored in accordance with the input process. please help

Comment: @url-snort yes I want to help u. Plz share yur form input fields

Comment: @url-snort can u share input fields

Comment: already I enter the picture above, you can check

[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yckza.jpg)

Comment: for auto input field can be added otomatis as we wish, I use auto save, for html output I just use id = "add" , include id `<input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-cons" id="tambah" value="Tambah" style="width:100px" />`

Comment: @url-snort than how r u getting this ($_POST['price'] and $_POST['type']... want to see both fields mate

Comment: I have tried and I enter in javascript but it does not work, the file is not stored. I enter in javascript  `  sb("#add").click(function(){
                sb('#konten').append(
                           '<tr class="baris">'
                         + '<td><input name="price[]" type="text"></td>'
       + '<td><input name="type[]" type="text"></td>'
                         + '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-cons" id="hapus" value="Hapus" style="width:100px" /></tr>'
       
                    );
                }); `

Comment: @url-snort ahan congrats... now dont forgot to mark as accepted the best answer and happy new year

Comment: hahaha I'm sorry devro, I mistyped the keyboard, the data still can not run. I mean, I've tried, but the data can not be saved. can you help me back, why can not data field to be stored

Comment: I made it like this ` if($_POST['tambah']==""){
  $i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['harga'] as $key => $keyWarna){ 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hargaproduk (id_produk, harga, tipe) VALUES ('$_POST[id_produk]', '$keyWarna','$_POST[tipe][$i]'"); 

$i++;
}
 }` Data become can not be stored

Comment: @url-snort and I also shared the same way.. in my update 3

Comment: Alrigt.  Use print_r($_POST[tipe]); and chk what u get in this array and share it to me @url-snort

Comment: The array data type does not seem to function, seems to be incorrectly processed function, ` $i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['price'] as $key => $keyWarna)
{ 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pricedata
(id_data, price, type) VALUES ('$_POST[id_data]', '$keyWarna','$_POST[type][$i]'"); 

$i++;
}` 
all table data is not stored in the database

Comment: if my input like this, `if($_POST['add']==""){
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['price'] as $keyWarna){
        mysql_query("insert into pricedata set id_data='$_POST[id_data]', price='$keyWarna', type='$_POST[type][$i]'");
    $i++;
    }
}` the data generated from the database in tabel type is Array[0], Array[1], Array[2], Array[3] if I make a 4 input table but, I input the data did not appear, he became such an array

Comment: @url-snort my friend ist of all I told u plz chk what r u getting in print_r($_POST); exit; chk the result of post array

Comment: devpro yes, as I described above